# How to change icon of pressed JLabel

Tags: java, swing, icons, jlabel, mouselistener

I'm currently trying to write a minesweeper game in Java using NetBeans for a school project. I've come across a big problem that I can't solve by myself and can't find any solution online either. I've created 100 JLabels with icons, added them to an array, then I've added a MouseListener to each of them. As I press on them I want their icon to change, but I don't really know how to get to the icon of the pressed label and change it. Any ideas?

That's a MouseListener class:

```
package MineSweeper;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

class myMouseListener implements MouseListener{

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) { }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0){ }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0){ }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0){ }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
        try{
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\SAPER\\grafika\\30x30\\pole odkryte.png"));
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            //THATS THE PLACE I WANT THE ICON TO CHANGE
            
            
        }catch (Exception x){}
    }
}
```

And that's minesweeper's field class:

```
package MineSweeper;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class pola{
    
    public int numer_w_tabeli;               //zmienne pola
    public int koord_x;
    public int koord_y;
    
    public int czy_odkryte;
    public int rodzaj_pola;
    
    public static JLabel pole;
    public pola(int x, int y, int i, int czy, int rodzaj){              //konstruktor pola
        
        koord_x = x;
        koord_y = y;
        numer_w_tabeli = i;
        czy_odkryte = czy;
        rodzaj_pola = rodzaj;
        pole = new JLabel();
        
        try{
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\SAPER\\grafika\\30x30\\pole.png"));
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
            pole.setIcon(icon);
            pole.setBounds(x,y,30,30);
        }catch(Exception e){} 
    }
}
```

And that's window class:

```
package MineSweeper;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Okno extends JPanel {
    
    public int x = 0;
    public int y = 0;
    
    public int numer_tablicy = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    
    public int iloscPol = 100;
    public int rozmiarX = 10;
    public int rozmiarY = 10;
    public int iloscBomb = 10;
    
    public pola[] tablica = new pola[iloscPol];
    
    public Okno() throws IOException{
        
        setLayout(null);
        
        for(i = 0; i < rozmiarY; i++){
            for(j = 0; j < rozmiarX; j++){
                tablica[numer_tablicy] = new pola(x,y,numer_tablicy,0,0);
                add(tablica[numer_tablicy].pole);
                
                myMouseListener m1 = new myMouseListener();         //dodanie do pola listenera
                tablica[numer_tablicy].pole.addMouseListener(m1);
                
//                System.out.println(x);
                x += 30;
                numer_tablicy++;
            }
            j = 0;
            x = 0;
            y += 30;
        }
        wylosuj_i_przydziel(iloscBomb,tablica,iloscPol);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(300,300);
    }
    
    public void dodajListener(){
        
    }
    
    public void wylosuj_i_przydziel(int iloscBomb, pola[] tablica, int iloscPol){
        
        int pozycjeBomb[] = new int[iloscBomb];
        int losowa = 0;
        boolean powtorka = false;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < iloscBomb; i++)
        {
            losowa = (int)(Math.random()*iloscPol-1);
            
            for(int j = 0; j < pozycjeBomb.length; j++){
                
                if(losowa == pozycjeBomb[j]){
                    break;  
                }
                else pozycjeBomb[j] = losowa;
            }
            System.out.println(pozycjeBomb[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use a JLabel. Instead use a JButton. It already supports methods for a pressed Icon. You can make the button look like a label by using  `setBorderPainted(false)` on each button.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).